# How can I make operator++ proceed to the next node pointer in a linked list?

Tags: c++, struct

I've got a linked list where I save data, and a pointer to next node, `Node<T>* next`, like this:

```
template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node<T>* next;
};
```

The thing is I want to put in this a post-increment operator, so it returns the previous value of my node, but increment the reference. So if I do this

```
Node<int>* someNode = someList.SomeNode();
Node<int>* tmp = someNode++;
```

`tmp` would be the original `someNode` value, but `someNode` would be `someNode->next`.

is it possible to put an operator in the struct? I've tried to, and searched how to do it, but as I don't deal with operators I don't know how to do.

Comment: "is it possible to put an operator in the struct?" Yes. Remember in C++ a struct can have member functions, just like a class.

Comment: A struct is equivalent to a class but for two things; the default access modifier is public, and inheritance is public by default as well.  Anything else is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks but I still having trouble doing someNode++; with the member Michael Krelin told me. The reason is someNode is a pointer Node<T>* no Node<T>, if i try *someNode++ MVC tell me I can't cast

Comment: The `++` binds more tightly than the `*` in that expression, Freesoul. You'd need parentheses: `tmp = (*someNode)++`. But your next problem will be that you're no longer operating on `someNode`, so its value won't change to become `someNode->next` like you wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot add member function to basic type like pointer.

What are you trying to define is an iterator. Use wrapper class over your node pointer to succeed:

```
template <class T>
struct NodeIterator
{
  NodeIterator(Node<T>* current) : current(current) {}
  NodeIterator& operator ++() { current = current->next; return *this; }
  NodeIterator operator ++(int) { 
      NodeIterator retVal = *this; 
      ++(*this);
      return retVal;
  }
  T* operator-> () const { return &current->data; }   
  T& operator * () const { return current->data; }   
  Node<T>* current;
};
```

See `std::slist<>` [implementation](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/libstdc++/html_user/stl__list_8h-source.html) for references. Look at `template<typename _Tp> struct _List_iterator`. Reading STL implementation is better than many books.

Usage:

```
NodeIterator<T> it =  &node;
++it;
T& t = *it;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Node<T>& operator++(int) {…}
```

is the member you want to implement.

Comment: True, but I was wrong in my code, someNode is a pointer, i just edited

Comment: I wouldn't want to do that, but then it's a `Node<T>* operator++(Node<T>*& p,int)`, I believe.

Comment: I get 'operator ++' has too many formal parameters
I'm just wondering why I shouldn't do that?

Comment: `operator++` is always a member function; it never takes more than one parameter, and when it takes a parameter, it's always a dummy int to distinguish post- from pre-increment.

Comment: @RobKennedy, I'm relieved to hear that ;-)

Comment: @freesoul and to answer your question, I'd feel really weird having destroyed expected functionality for pointer.

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work, you'd need to be able to define `operator++` for your pointer class. That's not allowed, though. You're welcome to define some other named function, though. For example:

```
template <typename Node>
Node goto_next(Node& node) {
  Node result = node;
  node = node->next;
  return result;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Node<int>* tmp = goto_next(someNode);
```

Another option is to provide a real iterator class instead of just using a pointer:

```
Node<int>::iterator someNode = someList.begin();
Node<int>::iterator tmp = someNode++;
```

Make your iterator keep a `Node<T>*` member, and make the `++` operator update that internal pointer before it returns a copy of the iterator object.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do that. The idea of using `++` on a pointer is dangerously close to the common iterator pattern. You should just go the full distance and make a real iterator class. Think of `std::list<T>::iterator`.

Iterators are very lightweight wrappers to give a sensible interface to a node pointer, which provides things like `operator ++` to move to the next node, and overloads `operator ->` to provide simple access to the node data. Converting client code from using a pointer to using an iterator is very straight-forward because the syntax is almost identical.